# How to keep EdgeForm Thickness within GeoBoundsRegion in GeoGraphics?

Tags: graphics, geographics

I have several abutting `GeoBoundsRegion`s that I need to colour with thick borders. The issue I am having is that `EdgeForm@Thickness` results in the borders being half in and half out of the regions.

```
GeoGraphics[{EdgeForm@Thickness[.05],
  EdgeForm[Blue], 
  (* GeoStyling[ ... ] *)
  GeoBoundsRegion[{{40.75874874700659`, 40.76325125211236`}, 
                   {-73.97876068957193`, -73.97283921053673`}}],
  EdgeForm[Red], 
  (* GeoStyling[ ... ]  *)
  GeoBoundsRegion[{{40.754248745245526`, 40.75875125387347`}, 
                   {-73.9737604899343`, -73.9678394101969`}}],
  EdgeForm[Purple], 
  (* GeoStyling[ ... ] *)
  GeoBoundsRegion[{{40.75874874700659`, 40.76325125211236`}, 
                   {-73.9728606895719`, -73.96693921053671`}}]
 }]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

This post ([58093](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58093)) suggest that there is sort of a lose work around with filled curves.  However, I cannot use this solution as there is a custom `GeoStyling` on each of the regions.

Is there a way to only draw the `EdgeForm` inside (or on one side) of the border?

Comment: If your regions are always rectangular can you not shrink them by the thickness of the border?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard Wouldn't there be issues with the amount to shrink them by? There are clusters of locations at different latitudes and the distances to shrink would not be constant across all latitudes. How would the conversion from pixels as a percentage of the screen width of the map (the units of `Thickness`) convert to either distance units or angular degree units to effect the shrinking?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't thought through these things, and I don't have `GeoBoundsRegion` in version 10.1 to play with.  It *seems* like if the regions are rectangular there should be some conversion factor that would be appropriate to achieve this.  As I commented on the linked Q&A this is a longstanding gap in *Mathematica*'s* general graphics functionality and sadly there seems to be no plan to fix it. :-(

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that I can use `FilledCurve` ([58093](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/58093)) for `GeoGraphics`.

```
ClearAll[geoSquareBorder];
geoSquareBorder[
  location_GeoPosition,
  length_Quantity?(UnitDimensions[#] == {{"LengthUnit", 1}} &),
  border_Quantity?(UnitDimensions[#] == {{"LengthUnit", 1}} &)] :=
 Line@FoldList[GeoDestination, location,
      {
       GeoDisplacement[{First[\[FormalC] /. 
           Solve[{(#1)^2 + (#1)^2 == \[FormalC]^2, \[FormalC] > 0}, \[FormalC], Reals]], 
         "SouthWest"}, "Rhumb"],
       GeoDisplacement[{#2, "North"}, "Rhumb"],
       GeoDisplacement[{#2, "East"}, "Rhumb"],
       GeoDisplacement[{#2, "South"}, "Rhumb"],
       GeoDisplacement[{#2, "West"}, "Rhumb"]
       }] & @@@ {
    {length/2, length}, {length/2 - border, length - 2 border}
    } // FilledCurve
```

`geoSquareBorder` passes a list of `GeoDisplacement`s to `GeoDestination` to the the vertices of the square starting from the center point; hence Pythagoras for the first displacement.  The list of `GeoDisplacement`s as a second parameter is not supported but it works. I do wonder how I could get these vertices with supported syntax.

Then

```
GeoGraphics[{GeoStyling[],
  Blue,
  geoSquareBorder[GeoPosition[{40.761`, -73.9758`}], 
   Quantity[500, "Meters"], Quantity[50, "Meters"]],
  Red,
  geoSquareBorder[GeoPosition[{40.7565`, -73.9708`}], 
   Quantity[500, "Meters"], Quantity[50, "Meters"]],
  Purple,
  geoSquareBorder[GeoPosition[{40.761`, -73.9699`}], 
   Quantity[500, "Meters"], Quantity[50, "Meters"]],
  }]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

This creates a square with sides 500 meters with a border that extends 50 meters inward from the edge. Abutting squares no longer over-print the borders of their neighbours.

Comment: Nice self-answer :-)